# Socket.io: emit from client does not work

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to emit an event on the client, but the server does not respond at all. A message does not appear in the console ('Received!'), the following event is not initiated. The event must emit when the button is clicked. Other actions, such as outputting a message to the console, work fine, but the event does not start. What is the problem? Сonnection events work properly.

Server:

```
class ChatHandlers {
    constructor() {
        this.names = {};

        this.connection = this.connection.bind(this);
        this.send = this.send.bind(this);
        this.message = this.message.bind(this);
    }

    connection(socket) {
        socket.emit('new_user', { 
            name: 'Example name'
        });
    }

    send(socket) {
        console.log('Received!');
        var ip = socket.handshake.address;
        io.sockets.emit('message', {
            name: ip,
            message: socket.message
        });
    }

    message(socket) {
        console.log('Success!');
    }
}

var handlers = new ChatHandlers();

io.on('connection', handlers.connection);
io.on('send', handlers.send);
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');

socket.on('connect', function (data) {
    socket.on('new_user', function (data) {
        console.log(data.name);
    });

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    $('#send').click(function() {
        socket.emit('send', {
            message: $('#mess').val()
        });

        $('#mess').val('');
    });
```

Comment: Try to place the last servers line `io.on('send', handlers.send);` to `connection(socked)` method below the line `socket.emit('new_user'...`

Comment: There's no need to put your message handlers inside of `socket.on('connect', ...)`.

Comment: `io.on('send', handlers.send);` is wrong on the server side.  You need to listen to a particular connected socket, not to `io`.